# Как связать int с void c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, label

Ошибка не удается преобразовать тип void в int, что я неправильно делаю.
Метод находится -

```
public class ModelCount : OnProperyChangedClass............
 public void Main(object obj)
    {
        CountInt = ob.Act();
    }


<Window
x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="800"
Height="250"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding AllModelCount}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="{Binding CountInt}"
        FontSize="50" />
    <Button
        Grid.Row="1"
        Width="100"
        Height="50"
        Command="{Binding}"
        Content="Click" />
</Grid>
```

```
  public class ToModelCount
{
    int a = 50;
    int b = 50;
    int c;
    public void Act()
    {
        c = a + b;
    }
}

public class ModelCount : OnProperyChangedClass
{
    int countInt;
    ToModelCount ob = new ToModelCount();
    public int CountInt
    {
        get
        {
            return countInt;
        }
        set
        {
            countInt = value;
            OnAllPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public void Main(object obj)
    {
        CountInt = ob.Act();
    }
    ICommand command;
    public ICommand Command => command ?? (command = new RelayCommand(Main));
}
```

}

```
 public class MainViewModel : OnProperyChangedClass
{
    public ModelCount allmodelCount = new ModelCount();
    public ModelCount AllModelCount
    {
        get
        {
            return allmodelCount;
        }
        set
        {
            allmodelCount = value;
            OnAllPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `public void Act()` и `CountInt = ob.Act();` ?

Comment: Да - абсолютно верно.

Comment: тогда я не понял вопроса

Comment: Вопрос никак правильно с формулировать не могу, у меня не получается запустить именно через Void метод, вот через int всё получается, а как только Void подключаю сразу же ругается, что не удается преобразовать void в int, догнать не могу, что неправильно делаю.

Comment: ну это просто - `void` - это не `int`, и не может быть приведен к `int`. Собственно, `void` - не может быть приведен ни к чему, поскольку функция, помеченная как `void`, не возвращает ничего, даже пустого значения не возвращает.

Comment: Т.е. вариантов получается нет? Просто читая о консольном приложении c# , фактически все примеры в конце концов сводятся к void, ну и соответственно на этом я останавливаюсь и не могу ничего сделать, вернее не понимаю.

Comment: вариантов чего? Если вам надо что то вернуть из функции, то измените определение функции, например так `public int Act()`

Comment: Да у меня так получилось, но читая книгу о консольном приложении, там всё сводится к void, вот я и застрял на этом.

Comment: я не знаю, что вы там читаете, но точно вам скажу, `void` вы никаким образом в `int` не превратите.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо вам.

Comment: @Евгений Если хотите вызвать void метод то просто пропишите его вызов: `obj.Act();`

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное.

Comment: Поясните, где вы собираетесь вернуть int? в методе Act? измените void на int, а вместо "c = a + b;" напишите "return c = a + b;". Естественно, объявите c в int и добавьте параметры, которые вы хотите передать в этот метод.

Comment: Так я именно решил попробовать вариант через void, через int у меня получилось.

Comment: Надо было оказывается к int a,b,c, всего лишь добавить акcессоры get set и всё заработало.